# Unlock recovered iPod after losing it and setting Lost Mode, and test it

Tags: icloud, ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

**Story of a lost (and incredibly recovered?) iPod**

I purchased an iPod 5 on Aug '14, it has iOS 7.1.1.
I lost it in Jan '15. I did not have any credit card info in the device.

**Background info**

The iPod had an 8-letter lock to use it. I also entered a restrictions 4-digit password.
WiFi and GPS were off.
Within a couple of hours of losing it, I went to iCloud, and set Lost Mode for the iPod. I also set a custom message, showing my phone contact number.
As per [official documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365),

> *Lost Mode locks your screen with a four-digit passcode*.
>   I do not remember that code now, I would have to try.

For some time I was tracking the iPod in my iCloud, and it always showed offline.

**Current status**

Yesterday (6 months later!) I received a contact in my phone about the iPod.
I am confident that many things (including torture) were tried on the device to unlock it, and I was contacted only because they failed.

---

I will pick up the iPod during this weekend, so I want to be ready to try it out on the spot.

*Question #1*:
What would I need to unlock it?

As per [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201472),

> *How do you turn off or cancel Lost Mode?*
>   
>   *You can turn off Lost Mode by entering the passcode on your device. You can also turn off Lost Mode on iCloud.com or from the Find My iPhone app*.

I do not remember the passcode, but I see it in my iCloud (which I used for setting Lost Mode).
I guess I also need it to be online, so I have to be next to a router to which it was previously connected.

---

*Question #2*:
If I manage to unlock it, what should I quickly test (in, say, 3 minutes) as essential to get an idea if it is functional, despite presumed torture.

Thanks

Comment: First, providing the iDevice is obviously not physical damaged then as a reward I'd give nothing more then a nominal amount regardless.  Second, you may have to take the iDevice along with proof of purchase to an Apple store or authorized service center to gain access to the iDevice if you cannot remember the passcode.

Comment: @user3439894 - Please note that I see the iPod in my iCloud (I edited the OP, I was checking the wrong iCloud account). I guess this means that the passcode is not needed. Is that correct?