# iPod in Lost Mode went online. I did not receive email notification

Tags: icloud, ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

I lost an iPod 5, with iOS 7.1.1. It had Find My Iphone enabled. 
WiFi and GPS were off.
Within a couple of hours of losing it, I went to iCloud, and set Lost Mode for the iPod. I also set a custom message for it to display my phone contact number. And I also set Notify me when found.

Yesterday I received a contact in my phone about the iPod, thanks to the custom message.
I guess this means that the iPod went online.

But I did never receive any email notification.

Why is that?

PS: The question does not have an answer in the other tagged question. They are different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unlock recovered iPod after losing it and setting Lost Mode, and test it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195492/unlock-recovered-ipod-after-losing-it-and-setting-lost-mode-and-test-it)

Comment: Are you surprised that email is unreliable (enough that one specific message could get delayed or not ever deliver) or is there another practical question you have?

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? "Updates" —or similar— inbox in Gmail?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD - The questions were triggered by the same device/situation. But they are completely different. Moreover, they are quite specific, and stated explicitly as questions. I wonder how you suspected they are possible dupes...

Comment: @bmike - You are aiming at unreliability of delivery. That is always an option. But perhaps there was a different, clear reason for this. Then the question.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz - Yes, I did. Nothing there.